# Параллельное выполнение контекстов

Tags: c#, база-данных, многопоточность, entity-framework

Есть код:

```
public class OpDispatcher
{
    //...
    public void Dispatch(...)
    {
        lock (typeof(OpDispatcher))
        {
            try
            {
                repoContainer.DBHelper.Open(); //Начало транзакции (новый контекст)
                if (opDispatcher.Verify(..params..))
                {
                     opDispatcher.Work();
                     opDispatcher.Log();
                     repoContainer.DBHelper.Save(); //ctx.SaveChanges()
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                repoContainer.DBHelper.Close(); //Конец транзакции
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В разных потоках создаются и выполняются `OpDispatcher`-ы.

При `lock (typeof(OpDispatcher))` всё проходит не параллельно, т.к. ждут снятия `lock`'а.

При `lock (this)` всё проходит параллельно, но иногда появляется ошибка:

> ERROR Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Адресат вызова создал исключение. ---> System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.
>      --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
>      в System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      в System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__2()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__1()
>      в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      в SLogic.ServerOperations.HandleEmpireOrders.Work(String& message) в d:\Projects\IUV4\SLogic\ServerOperations\HandleEmpireOrders.cs:строка 29
>      в SLogic.Operations.OpDispatcher.Dispatch(IOpDispatcher opDispatcher, Boolean serialize, Object[] parameters) в d:\Projects\IUV4\SLogic\Operations\OpDispatcher.cs:строка 41

Какой вариант оставить? Первый железный, но при большом количестве потоков могут появиться "фризы". Второй почему-то выкидывает эту ошибку.

Comment: сделал в каждом потоке свой контекст, на всякий случай добавил lock с переменной, чтобы случайно никто не вызвал 2 штуки в потоке. Проблема вроде пропала. Но пока не ясно, из-за чего вызывалось исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Это не совсем ответ, скорее предостережение: оба варианта lock неправильные. Категорически не рекомендуется использовать ни **lock(this)** ни **lock(typeof(Something))** потому что у вас нет гарантии, что кто-то еще не использует this или typeof(Something) в других локах, а это может быть чревато дедлоками. Правильной практикой считается lock с помощью приватной переменной, специально для этого предназначенной

Answer (score 1):

По вашему кусочку кода поблему найти трудно.
Постарайтесь сделать так, чтобы в каждом потоке был свой EF Context, тогда можно будет избавится от локов вообще.